# Why would a Conditional Compilation Symbol not be detected in Release build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a WPF solution containing a sub-project component with WPF and Silverlight code. If the "WPF" Conditional Compilation Symbol is defined, the WPF code is built and if it is not defined then the Silverlight code is built. This works for my Debug builds just fine. However, when I attempt to do a Release build, the build does not detect the "WPF" Symbol and because it then incorrectly compiles the silverlight code I get a build that will not work. Any ideas why the WPF symbol is not being detected by the build?

Here is the relevant section of the .csproj. Note the "WPF" symbol is defined in DefineConstants for both Debug and Release, yet its not being detected in release builds. Can anyone help?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;WPF</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <NoWarn>1607</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;WPF</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Define "not being detected" - which preprocessor directives did you apply?

Comment: @KMoraz the preprocessor directives (Symbols) are applied via the project properties > Build tab > Conditional compilation symbols field; which is stored in the .csproj file in the DefineConstants tag as demonstrated above. As I understand it, this is the same as #define TRACE #define WPF etc

Comment: @KMoraz by "not being detected" I mean that I have "#if WPF" statements in my code but while this works as expected for Debug builds the Release version builds as if the WPF preprocessor directive does not exist thus compiling the wrong code into the build

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, I think you may need to update your build definition to include something like:

```
/p:DefineConstants="WPF"
```

This is in the Build definition under Process > Advanced > MSBuild Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your definitions are specified for all configurations DEBUG and RELEASE and any others you may have.